# Formatting the output from Pandas .groupby.size()

Tags: python, pandas

I'm working with pandas and I have a dataframe that looks something like this.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'AAA' : [4,5,6,7], 'BBB' : [100,100,30,40],'CCC' : [100,100,30,-50]})
```

And I'm using .groupby() and .size() to find duplicate rows in only the 'BBB' and 'CCC' columns and turning the result into a dataframe like this :

```
duplicates=df.groupby(['BBB','CCC']).size().to_frame('num')
```

I find the format of this new dataframe duplicates hard to work with, even though it has all the data that I need inside of it.  It looks like this when I look at it in the Variable explorer in Spyder:

```
Index       num
(30,30)     1
(40,-50)    1
(100,100)   2
```

So the index contains the values of 'BBB' and 'CCC' that were repeated and num contains how many times they were repeated.  I don't know how to access data from the index and parse it into the individual columns so the index is really the hardest thing to work with.  I would really like it if instead the output looked like this

```
Index     'BBB'     'CCC'   num
0            30       30      1
1            40      -50      1
2           100      100      2
```

P.S.
Sorry if the formatting is bad I still haven't found how to post well on this site.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

is that ([reset_index()](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html)) what you want?

```
In [24]: df.groupby(['BBB','CCC']).size().to_frame('num').reset_index()
Out[24]:
   BBB  CCC  num
0   30   30    1
1   40  -50    1
2  100  100    2
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the amazingly quick and perfect response!   I will call it an answer as soon as I can you answered it so quickly I have to wait five minutes!

Comment: @mikevandernaald, sure, always glad to help :)